# Verify if a element have a specific element by name

Tags: google-apps-script

With google-apps-script, i try to verify if a element have a specific element. I try to do this with the name of the element, verifying:

```
var results=doc.getElement().getElements();
Browser.msgBox(results[0].getElement("name").getText()); //results[0] have a element "name"
Browser.msgBox(results[0].getElement("name1").getText()); //results[0] no have a element name1, show nothing
```

I try with `Browser.msgBox(results[0].getElement("name1").getText()!==undefined)` but show nothing (true or false)

Comment: please post a sample of your "doc" so we can see what you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do
`var results=doc.getElement().getElements('byName'); if (0 < results.length) Browser.msgBox(results[0].getName()+' found '+results.length+' time(s)');`

should return: **byName found 1 time(s)** (if any)